# Lobachevsky's Formula for Integrals

Tags: improper-integrals

If the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x+\pi)=f(\pi-x)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then 
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{\sin x }{x} \mathrm{d}x = \int _0^\frac\pi2 f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

How can I prove this equality?

Comment: I believe the function you described doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: @vonbrand surely your $f$ does not satisfy the conditions in the first line of the question.  Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indeed, let
$$I=\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$
By asumption $f$ is even and $\pi$-periodic. Moreover,
$$\eqalign{
2I&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}f(x)dx
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}f(x)dx\cr
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^n\int_{0}^{ \pi}\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k\pi}\sin(x)f(x)dx\cr
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{ \pi}\left(\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k\pi}\right)\sin(x)f(x)dx\cr
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{ \pi}U_n(x)f(x)dx\cr
}
$$
with
$$
U_n(x) =\sin(x)\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k\pi}
$$
But it is well-known that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}U_n(x)=1$ for every $x\in(0,\pi)$ and that the sequence $\{U_n\}$ is bounded on $[0,\pi]$, so, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we conclude that
$$
2I=\int_0^\pi f(x)dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)dx.
$$
and the desired conclusion follows.

**Remark.** Concerning the statements about the sequence $\{U_n\}$ these are well-known, and a simple proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775750/fresh-integral-int-0-infty-frac-ln-cos2-xx2dx-pi/775893#775893). Indeed,
consider $\alpha\in(0,1)$, and let $f_\alpha$ be the $2\pi$-periodic function that coincides  with $x\mapsto e^{i\alpha x}$ on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. It is easy to check that the exponential Fourier coefficients of $f_\alpha$  are
given by
$$
C_n(f_\alpha)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f_\alpha(x)e^{-inx}dx=\sin(\alpha\pi)\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha \pi-n\pi}
$$
and since $f_\alpha$ is continuously differentiable on $(-\pi,\pi)$ the Fourier series of $f_\alpha$ converges to $f_\alpha$ on this interval:
$$
\forall\,x\in(-\pi,\pi),\quad e^{i\alpha x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}C_k(f_\alpha)e^{ikx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k\sin(\alpha\pi)}{\alpha\pi- k\pi}e^{ikx}
$$
Taking $x=0$, we get
$$
1=\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n(\alpha\pi)
$$

Comment: Thank you. I think you forgot a 1 (the limit of the sequence U). I am sorry, but I can't see the proof of that fact from the relationship given by Parseval's equality in the post that you referred.

Comment: You do not need Parseval's equality, just that the Fourier series converges at $0$.

Comment: I do apologize, but I would appreciate it if you could elaborate a little more.

Comment: I, hope it is clear now.

Comment: How do you obtain that the sequence $U_n$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: @izimath, Assume $n\ge 2$. By the remainder of the alternating series property we have $$\left|\sum_{k>n}\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi k +x}\right|\le \frac{1}{(1+n)\pi+x}\le\frac{1}{n\pi}$$ Similarly $$\left|\sum_{k> n}\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi k -x}\right|\le \frac{1}{(1+n)\pi-x}\le\frac{1}{n\pi}$$ Thus, for $0\le x\le \pi$ we have $$|U_n(x)|\le 1+\frac{2}{n\pi}\le 2$$.