# Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin x|\sin x}{x}dx=1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin x|\sin x}{x}dx=1.$$
I know how to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$, but the method cannot be applied here. So I am thinking 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x}dx$$
but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You have $$\int_0^\pi\,\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,\text{d}x=\frac12\,\big(\gamma+\ln(2\pi)-\text{Ci}(2\pi)\big)$$ and $$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\,\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\,\text{d}x=\frac12\,\Big( \text{Ci}(2k\pi)-\text{Ci}\big(2(k+1)\pi\big)+\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)\Big)$$ for integers $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Here, $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant, and $\text{Ci}$ is the cosine integral: $$\text{Ci}(z)=-\int_z^\infty\,\frac{\cos(t)}{t}\,\text{d}t\,.$$

Comment: That is, $$\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\sin(x)\,\big|\sin(x)\big|}{x}\,\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\,\big(\gamma+\ln(2\pi)\big)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,(-1)^k\,\text{Ci}(2k\pi)+\frac12\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,(-1)^{k}\,\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\,.$$  I am not sure whether this is helpful.  Mathematica seems to confirm that $$\frac{1}{2}\,\big(\gamma+\ln(2\pi)\big)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,(-1)^k\,\text{Ci}(2k\pi)+\frac12\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,(-1)^{k}\,\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=1\,.$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By Lobachevsky integral formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobachevsky_integral_formula
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}|\sin x|\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2}|\sin x|\,\mathrm{d}x=1.$$

Comment: +1. $\texttt{Mathematica}$ doesn't seem to know the Lobachevsky stuff.

Comment: https://youtu.be/m0o6pAeCcJs Michael Penn posted a nice video tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$ \left|\sin x\right|=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2-1} \tag{1} $$
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+,\quad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(2nx)}{x}\,dx=0\tag{2} $$
hence
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|\sin x\right|\sin x}{x}\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = 1.\tag{3}$$

Comment: (+1) Nicely done Jack.  No need to appeal to anything other that Fourier Series representation of $| \sin(x)|$ and the value of $\int_0^\infty \frac1{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$.

Comment: Why is $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(2nx)}{x}\,dx=0$ ? (some reference would do - thanks)

Comment: @Andreas: because $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(m x)}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for any $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and you may invoke the sine addition formulas.

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$I:=\int_0^\infty\,\frac{\big|\sin(x)\big|\,\sin(x)}{x}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
Therefore,
$$2I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{\big|\sin(x)\big|\,\sin(x)}{x}\,\text{d}x=\int_0^\pi\,\sin^2(x)\,\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{x+k\pi}\right)\,\text{d}x\,.$$
It can be [proven by residue calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963263/prove-cscx-sum-k-infty-infty-frac-1kxk-pi) that
$$\text{csc}(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{z+k\pi}\text{ for all }z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\pi\mathbb{Z}\,.$$
Thus,
$$2I=\int_0^\pi\,\sin^2(x)\,\text{csc}(x)\,\text{d}x=\int_0^\pi\,\sin(x)\,\text{d}x=2\,,$$
whence $I=1$.

Comment: Indeed, the proof of the Lobachevsky integral formula seems to be along similar lines https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776903/lobachevskys-formula-for-integrals

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Oh, nice!  I didn't realize that this proof can be extended to prove the Lobachesky Integral Formula.

Comment: @batominovski (+1) One need not use residue calculus to develop the partial fraction representation of the cosecant function, but can develop the representation using real analysis only.  See [THE APPENDIX OF THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576)